# How to define Mapped type with a non-optional subset of keys in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

I have this TypeScript code that neatly maps types to their possible values:

```js
export const randomMappings = {
  coin: ['heads', 'tails'],
  d4: [1, 2, 3, 4],
  d6: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
  d10: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
} as const;

export type RandomType = keyof typeof randomMappings;
export type RandomValue<T extends RandomType> = typeof randomMappings[T][number];
// RandomValue<'coin'> is 'heads'|'tails'; RandomValue<'d4'> is 1|2|3|4 and so on.
export type RandomResults = {
  [T in RandomType]?: RandomValue<T>;
};


export function pickRandomValues(types: RandomType[]): RandomResults {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    types.map((type) => [
      type,
      randomMappings[type][Math.floor(Math.random() * randomMappings[type].length)],
    ]),
  );
}
```

I would like to enforce that the type returned by `pickRandomValues` is a map that contains only the keys present in the argument `types` instead of having all possible keys as optional.

For example:

```js
const x = pickRandomValues(['coin', 'd6']);
console.log(x.coin, x.d6); //works
console.log(x.d10); //should fail because d10 is not present in x
```

I think the way `RandomValue<T>` is defined is quite elegant, so I would not like to change that if possible.

Is there any way to do that? I would not mind changing the `types` argument to a map instead of an array so I can do something like `{[T in keyof typeof types]: RandomValue<T>}`, but what I tried doesn't work because if I want it to allow to pass an object with just the keys I am interested in the type would be the same as `RandomResults` stands now (all keys optional).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make `pickRandomValues` generic over the values in `types`:

```
export function pickRandomValues<T extends RandomType>(
  types: T[]
): {[K in T]: RandomValue<K>} {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    types.map((type) => [
      type,
      randomMappings[type][Math.floor(Math.random() * randomMappings[type].length)],
    ]),
    // needs type assertion
  ) as {[K in T]: RandomValue<K>};
}

const coin = pickRandomValues(['coin'])
coin.coin // 'heads' | 'tails'
coin.d4 // error

const coinD4 = pickRandomValues(['coin', 'd4'])
coinD4.coin // 'heads' | 'tails'
coinD4.d4 // 1 | 2 | 3 | 4
coinD4.d10 // error
```

For example, in `pickRandomValues(['coin', 'd4'])`, `T` would be `'coin' | 'd4'` and the return type would be `{coin: RandomValue<'coin'>, d4: RandomValue<'d4'>}`.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7ygQ2QEwgWwFlMwwBLZAc1TgF44BvAKDkQgoC44BtAcgAtgmHKl4AaOLxiYyAG1EBdMSzg4ALF24BGCQCYJAZglqlKnADZNOuPrhG4aiQFYJ506xxaADJq8TrtvaOcC5w5hIA7BIAHBIAnKYAvnCYNEhoMADcTEygkLBwMACeYMBwAErYePgAKiVl9ADWwEUQAGaF9e1wWLgExKQU1Nl50PDFpRVVBABqmLIArsAAPDVwoDDAuDSVfbX1AHx0naXdvdUD5FSo3DUK3MgL+ABGwFAK2QD0n1N7c4srXhICi8I5kGgCIQiXgAHykMnkvEyv2q-yWy146lBcHBcC0MN0MIMMLUKVwcFQEDgKAAdLlwGMTmVdtVysBUAtZDAaPRmKxbjjkCiCHVSgoAPxcFmzebomoHbKJbI5UYFNoLZAIGBkFBwcgIRrS-Bo9mrdYgTbbYX7UoHAAUE3ZXBq3AUAEouAxuABpQVwO5S6bG2Urb0HZJ8nrAGALKBCgDyzwAVsAtTS2lACABRZAwKBkdl2lSsR2oGn4Eh2h31N10I7cYusJnKJtN879EhXajcR33Ygwfjp2QQaB2-uD9v4O21gBUPSDlyGN17NNkW0oA7d7ib7pbTe+cGQwGAIiZKVQqDe2pQKlrqUYPr9AetJuWYaVTESOXS6DYFGO+qGkGJqoHafDAsgvDukwEE0hBcAHpCwiiHAMKSNIciiDB7DIDS6gIT8byZlA34oL+EEACKkvQgFGiBYFAjh4iSFi0GUWocE4QRkiCMhvCoehCJYexeGkgeWgCboAkGAJajYRQVF4d43FEdATBAA)